# checking for illegal imports of remote.entities outside remote package

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

When the application needs to query a remote system, we often create a “remote” package, with an “entity” sub-package containing classes that will be easier to process the info we retrieve. These classes shouldn’t leak out of the remote package.

Is there any rule available (or under study) to check for importing x.y.remote.entities outside of x.y.remote package?

Comment: Dependency matrix view in earlier versions of Sonarqube would have been of good help with this but unfortunately this feature is removed in recent versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question tags, I see that a Checkstyle based solution would also be helpful to you. The [ImportControl](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#ImportControl) check should be just what you need. Checkstyle also features a [SonarQube plugin](https://github.com/checkstyle/sonar-checkstyle) should you require that.

Comment: Certainly ImportControl rule helps to check for forbidden class usage. But this rule throws violation for x.y.remote.entities used inside x.y.remote package too. Any idea on how to configure this rule to check for usage only outside x.y.remote package but not inside.

Answer (score 2):

[S3688](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS3688) was added in SonarJava 4.4 to forbid entirely the use of certain classes. On the face of it, that won't work because you *do* want to allow the use of those classes in some packages. That's where [Issue Exclusions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) come in.

You'll set up the rule to forbid the use of `x.y.remote.entities` (universally) then set up an exclusion to ignore issues from that rule raised on anything in `x.y.remote`.

Comment: this rule looks interesting to investigate further. But since which version of Java is this rule available. We are using Java 3.9 but I am not able to locate this rule.

Comment: See my edit @Coc. BTW you should really consider upgrading. 3.9 is well over a year old. Many improvements have been made since then. Current version is 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main strengths of PMD is that it allows to easily write custom rules that are very specific to a given project / team just as this one, by writing simple XPath expressions.

On the ruleset XML file, simply add your custom rule as follows:

```
<rule name="Remote entities used outside remote package"
      message="The remote entities should not be imported outside the remote package"
      class="net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule"
      language="java">
    <description>
        Remote entities should not be imported outside the remote package
    </description>
    <priority>3</priority>
    <properties>
        <property name="xpath">
            <value>
    //ImportDeclaration/Name[contains(@Image, '.entities') and //PackageDeclaration/Name[not(contains(@Image, '.remote'))]]
            </value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

Notice the rule as it stands allow all entities being imported from any remote package, but [using the designer](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.5/customizing/xpathruletutorial.html) you could probably iterate on this rule to narrow it down as much as you may need.

Comment: I am not sure how easy it is to write a rule to implement our scenario. I will give it a try and get back to you for clarifications if needed. Thanks again for the answer.